# Any text in desktop and menu is unreadable

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-sense

My girlfriend owns an HTC Desire X running Android 4.1.1 with HTC Sense 4+.

The phone was working fine but suddenly yesterday any text in desktop and menu has become unreadable. Instead of letters (european character, spanish) text is now made of white squares. Something  like having an issue with fonts. You can see a picture below.

My troubleshooting was:

- Asked her if she installed any update: she did not install any new app or software update.
- Restarted the phone but the issue was still present after reset
- As suggested in comments, verified that language is properly set

Today she installed 3 updates: Twitter, Chrome and Dropbox. Suddenly fonts in desktop and menu came back to normal and text is readable again.

Did any of you have similar issue? Any idea what could be the cause?

[image]

Comment: That is odd. Have you at least turned it off and back on?

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting the phone but it had no effect. It keeps the same after restart.

Comment: In `Settings > Language & Keyboard` check the language that is set. May be language has got changed.

Comment: Language is set to Spanish. It did not change.

Comment: Maybe try changing the language to something else and then back?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after rejecting installation of HTC sense keyboard (I chose 'later'). Nothing seemed to help, until after some random opening and closing of apps (specifically, I went to messages) the app-choser had the icons visible again.
Went to settings on this menu, and simply exited settings and the problem was 'solved'. (not really solved of course, I don't know why it occured and it may happen again).

Btw: exactly that one: the HTC desire X!